# System memory 259522560 must be at least 4.718592E8. Please use a larger heap size

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have this error when I run my Spark scripts with version 1.6 of Spark.
My scripts are working with version 1.5.

- Java version: 1.8
- scala version: 2.11.7

I tried to change the system env variable `JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx512m` many times, with different values of Xms and Xmx but it didn't change anything ...

I also tried to modify the memory settings of Intellij

- help/change memory settings...
- file/settings/scal compiler...

Nothing worked.

I have different users in the computer, and Java is setup at the root of the computer while intellij is setup in the folder of one of the users. Can it have an impact?

Here are the logs of the error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/04/30 17:06:54 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
20/04/30 17:06:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/04/30 17:06:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to:
20/04/30 17:06:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: 
20/04/30 17:06:55 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(); users with modify permissions: Set()
20/04/30 17:06:56 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 57698.
20/04/30 17:06:57 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
20/04/30 17:06:57 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
20/04/30 17:06:57 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.1.5.175:57711]
20/04/30 17:06:57 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 57711.
20/04/30 17:06:57 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
20/04/30 17:06:57 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 259522560 must be at least 4.718592E8. Please use a larger heap size.
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.getMaxMemory(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.apply(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:457)
    at batch.BatchJob$.main(BatchJob.scala:23)
    at batch.BatchJob.main(BatchJob.scala)
20/04/30 17:06:57 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 259522560 must be at least 4.718592E8. Please use a larger heap size.
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.getMaxMemory(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.apply(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:457)
    at batch.BatchJob$.main(BatchJob.scala:23)
    at batch.BatchJob.main(BatchJob.scala)
```

And the beginning of the code:

```scala
package batch

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SQLContext}


object BatchJob {
  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // get spark configuration
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Lambda with Spark")

    // Check if running from IDE
    if (ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments.toString.contains("IntelliJ IDEA")) {
      System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\Libraries\\WinUtils") // required for winutils
      conf.setMaster("local[*]")
    }

    // setup spark context
    val sc = new  SparkContext(conf)
    implicit val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally could find a solution:

add -Xms2g -Xmx4g in VM options directly in Intellij Scala Console.

That's the only thing that worked for me